# how to send photo from telegram bot api (javascript)

Tags: javascript, telegram, telegram-bot

I have a problem with sending the api via telegram text messages that arrive but the pictures are not arriving and I don't understand where the problem is
Is it possible to modify this code and make it send images?

```js
var telegram_bot_id = "api";
var chat_id = "id";
var img;
var ready = function () {
    img = document.getElementById("photo").value;
    message = "photo: " + img ;
};
var sender = function () {
    ready();
    var settings = {
        "async": true,
        "crossDomain": true,
        "url": "https://api.telegram.org/bot" + telegram_bot_id + "/sendPhoto",
        "method": "POST",
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "cache-control": "no-cache"
        },
        "data": JSON.stringify({
            "chat_id": chat_id,
            "text": message
        })
    };
    $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    
        window.location.href = "index.html";
    });
    document.getElementById("photo").value = "";
    return false;
};
```

Comment: what do you mean not arriving? also what kind of element is returned from the querySelector for the id 'value'?

Comment: I want to send pictures

Comment: yes. In order to help you, I need to know more details. Can you console.log the data on the receiving end to see what you are getting when you run this code?

Comment: When I send text messages it arrives and when I send pictures nothing happens

Comment: in both cases you are just sending a string representation of an object. So it would seem either something would arrive or an error would occur. "nothing happens" doesnt help us debug. Where ever you are receiving this, log it out and see what it says

Comment: I made a comment take a look

Comment: you can edit your question you didnt need to put an answer. also, this doesn't really help me out much. Can you tell me what `img` is when you send it?

Comment: 1-Uncaught ReferenceError: sender is not defined 2-Form contains a file input, but is missing method=POST and enctype=multipart/form-data on the form.  The file will not be sent. 3-Loading failed for the <script> with source “file:///C:/Users/PC/Desktop/script.js”.

Comment: 3 errors are displayed in the browser

Comment: can you show the code where you are calling sender?

Comment: https://ibb.co/K7rSVjx

Comment: when you are calling the sender function it is not defined. I would need to see the part in your code where you are running `sender()`

Comment: I don't have any other code, just the one in front of you

Comment: Where did you ever send a photo? You only have `text` in your request data.

Comment: According to the [API document](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendphoto), you need a `photo` field in the request body. And there should be no `text` field, text should be sent as `caption` in a `sendPhoto` request. You also need to [upload the file](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sending-files) on behalf.

Comment: @RickyMo it seems that you were faster than me: I'm sorry I didn't read your comment.

Indeed, before reading your comment, I wrote down the answer for him.

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to send a photo via *sendPhoto* method, **you have to send a proper picture file or a string represent a valid URL**.

According to code you posted, you're sending into the HTTP request as **body parameters** the chat_id, the text message itself and that's it.

The *[sendPhoto](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendphoto)* method does not expect a *text* field, that's used in *[sendMessage](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage)* method.

In your case, since you're trying to send via Telegram chatbot a picture taken from the HTML entity, which in this case ***is not the picture itself but its path on your webserver***, you have to change the **POST request body** and to set the **picture URL** as parameter of the request itself.

To conclude, if you want to add the **text message**, the *sendPhoto* method allows you to add it **but as *caption***.

For instance:

```
var telegram_bot_id = "api";
var chat_id = "id";
var img;
var ready = function () {    
    img = "http://your-website.com/imagepath/imagename.png";

};
var sender = function () {
    ready();
    var settings = {
        "async": true,
        "crossDomain": true,
        "url": "https://api.telegram.org/bot" + telegram_bot_id + "/sendPhoto",
        "method": "POST",
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "cache-control": "no-cache"
        },
        "data": JSON.stringify({
            "chat_id": chat_id,
            "photo": img,
            "caption": message

        })
    };
    $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    
        window.location.href = "index.html";
    });

    return false;
    
};
```